# Merging two dataframes with different size

Tags: r

I have two Data Frames with two columns. One column for date another for numeric data. The two Data Frames have different size. I give you an example of what I have and what I need.

This is what I have:

```
DF1
2015-01-02  0
2015-01-03  0
2015-01-04  0

DF2
2015-01-03  200
```

This is what I need:

```
DF1
2015-01-02  0
2015-01-03  200
2015-01-04  0
```

I have tried comparing (compare function) both DF but I have no solution.
Maybe this could help you (or even make the functions faster), in both DF the dates are sorted.

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much,
Gobya

Comment: When there are matching dates in the two frames, how do you decide which value will override?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you want to choose which row to select when there are matching dates from the two data frames (per @user295691's comment), so I've provided two selection options below that give the result you specified.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04"),
                  value = c(0, 0, 0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF2 <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-03"), value = c(200), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF1$source = "DF1"
DF2$source = "DF2"

library(dplyr)

# Choose the greatest value for each date
newDF = DF1 %>% bind_rows(DF2) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(value == max(value))

# If there are more than two values for a given date, 
# choose the value(s) from DF2 for that date
newDF = DF1 %>% bind_rows(DF2) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  filter(ifelse(n>1, source=="DF2", source=="DF1")) %>%
  select(-n)
```

FYI, for the second approach, I thought the following would work, but it excludes rows with date=2014-01-03. I'm not sure why and would be interested in any ideas on what's going wrong:

```
DF1 %>% bind_rows(DF2) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(ifelse(n() > 1, source=="DF2", source=="DF1"))

        date value source
1 2015-01-02     0    DF1
2 2015-01-04     0    DF1
```

Comment: Sorry, made a change in my approach, updated the second result, but forgot to update the first. Should be fixed now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I like the approach, but I get errors at the dplyr calls. `object 'value' not found`

Comment: Rerun the set-up code for `DF1` and `DF2`, then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `full_join()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04"),
                  number = c(0, 0, 0))
DF2 <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-03"), number = c(200))

DF3 <- full_join(DF1, DF2, by="date")

DF3$newColumn <- ifelse(is.na(DF3$number.y), DF3$number.x, DF3$number.y)
```

Comment: In vanilla R this is also straightforward; `merge(DF1, DF2, by="date", all.x=T)` -- I'm guessing full_join is basically an alias for this for `data.frame`s

Comment: Yes, this is true, user295691.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdf <- merge(DF1, DF2, by='V1', all=T)
newdf[,2][is.na(newdf[,2])] <- newdf[,3][!is.na(newdf[,3])]
newdf[-3]
#           V1 V2.x
# 1 2015-01-02    0
# 2 2015-01-03  200
# 3 2015-01-04    0
```